# Открытие ссылок в другой вкладке

Tags: предложение, ссылки

А на сколько реально добавить функционал, чтобы при клике по ссылкам на странице, ссылка открывалась в другой вкладке, а не в текущей? Реально достает это. Пример:

- в правом бэнде высветился вопрос на мете. Я щелкнул на нее и с текущего вопроса/списка вопросов и оказался на мете
- в вопросе кто-то поместил картинку. Я кликнул на картинку, у меня открылась картинка, а вопрос потерялся
- кто-то в вопросе/ответе оставил ссылку на внешний ресурс/другой вопрос - тоже потерял вопрос

Мои предложения:

- любая ссылка в вопросе открывается в новой вкладке
- любая ссылка в списке вопросов, ведущая на другой домен, открывается в другой вкладке
- все ссылки на странице списка вопросов, ведущие на текущий домен открываются в той-же вкладке
- все ссылки из заголовка страницы, кроме ссылок перехода на другой сайт сети StackExchange открываются на текущей вкладке

По алгоритму, может еще кто что добавит, но ключевой вопрос на сколько реально добавить функционал?

Comment: Но ведь есть средняя кнопка мышки. Сейчас есть возможность открывать ссылки и в текующей вкладке и в новой. Если принудительно открывать их в новой - открыть в текущей уже не получится.

Comment: @Nofate Собственно, сейчас так и делаю. Уже почти не забываю об этом. Но когда забыл - р-р-р! Если можно изначально упростить жизнь, то пуркуа бы и не па? Мне, описанное поведение ссылок, кажется удобным и логичным

Comment: Решение, которое повлияет на всех участников -- не очень хороший вариант, у каждого свои умолчания. Если вы забываете -- лучше поищите плагины в ваш браузер, которые будут принудительно открывать в новой вкладке ссылки.

Comment: Ну и ещё всегда есть кнопка "назад" чтобы вернуться, если вдруг случайно открыли в текущей вкладке.

Answer (score 6):

Я против такого предложения.

Участников много и даже из двух самых очевидных вариантов ("всегда открывать в новой вкладке" и "всегда открывать в той же вкладке") окажется, что пользовательские предпочтения окажутся разными.

А если предпочтения разделятся не как 80% и 20% за каждый вариант, а примерно "половина на половину"?

А вы не просто предлагаете два варианта, а детализируете ("ссылки в этом блоке -- новая вкладка", "ссылки в этом блоке -- текущая вкладка"), поэтому число возможных вариантов пользовательских предпочтений начинает резко возрастать.

Более-менее простой способ будет возможен только для зарегистрированных участников (настройки в профиле), а для незарегистрированных нужно всё равно будет выбирать из тех же двух базовых вариантов всегда в новом/текущем окне.

Мне кажется, что нет смысла менять текущее поведение. Пусть каждый участник делает так, как сложились его личные предпочтения.

Кто-то будет открывать ссылки с нажатой клавишей Ctrl, кто-то -- жать среднюю кнопку мыши.

Если у вас есть какие-то предпочтения, то вероятно можно посоветовать вам более индивидуально настроить браузер.

Например, в Firefox есть расширение [Right Links](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/right-links/) которое всегда открывает ссылки всегда в новой вкладке, возможно есть и другие.

Comment: Если мы говорим о возможности хранения настроек, то можно добавить только две опции `Все в одном` (как сейчас) и `New style` (предложенный алгоритм)

Comment: @AntonShchyrov опции не в почёте на SO, их стараются минимизировать, т.е. чтобы у всех участников было всё единообразно по большому счёту. Исключения делаются только в особых случаях, когда мнения о том, как должно быть, разительно отличаются. Например так было с прилипанием верхней панели.

Answer (score 3):

Я против. Все перечисленные ссылки (хотя изображения под вопросом) мне удобно открывать в новой *фоновой* вкладке. Потому что я хочу открыть несколько ссылок, либо дочитать обсуждение, а не переключаться сразу на чтение другой страницы. С сайта так сделать нельзя, так что выходит, что случай открытия на ненужной мне странице в той же вкладке более полезен, чем открытие в новой.

А для изображений давно пора сделать модальное окно.

Comment: Вот модальное окно, это да! Поддержал [предложение](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151793/339911)!

Comment: Нельзя? А ка же shift-ctrl-click?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, во-первых, порсто ctrl+click, во-вторых, сайт не может сделать такое поведение дефаултным для ссылок.